# Never ending menu system database driven

Tags: php, mysql, menu

I'm working on a menu system that I would like to have unlimited children.

I have it reading from the database and showing the second child under the parent but this will only allow me to have 1 child. How can I make it repeat until there are no more children left?

I can just copy the above code but I want to keep adding entries to the database and keep creating more children when needed.

```
$get_top_menu = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ss_folderstructure WHERE folderstructure_parent='0'");
while($found_top_menu = mysqli_fetch_array($get_top_menu))
        {

            echo "<li class='dropdown' ><a href=''><span class='icon-folder-open'></span>" . $found_top_menu['folderstructure_name'] . "</a>";
                echo "<ul>";

                        $get_mid_menu = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ss_folderstructure WHERE folderstructure_parent='" . $found_top_menu['folderstructure_idno'] . "'");
                        while($found_mid_menu = mysqli_fetch_array($get_mid_menu))
                                    {       
                                    echo "<li><a href='bootstrap.html'>" . $found_mid_menu['folderstructure_name'] . "</a></li>";                                                                                       
                                    }
                echo "</ul>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may fetch all data from the database using one query. And form array from the results.

like:

```
$result = array();
$get_top_menu = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ss_folderstructure");
while($found_top_menu = mysqli_fetch_array($get_top_menu)) {
 $result[$found_top_menu['folderstructure_parent']][] = $found_top_menu;
}
```

After this you should use recursion:

```
function doLoop($foo,$currId) {
   echo "<ul>";
   foreach ($foo[$currId] as $bar) {
    if (isset($bar['folderstructure_idno'])) {
      echo "<li>";
      doLoop($foo,$bar['folderstructure_idno']);
      echo "</li>";
    } else {
      echo "<li><a>{$bar['folderstructure_name']}</a></li>";
    }
   }
   echo "</ul>";
   return true;
}

doLoop($result,0);
```